# Java Error: Could not find or load main class - CommandPrompt & Eclipse

Tags: java

Program In Java:
I wrote a program written in java and tried to compile in command prompt (which succeeded) however an attempt to run the program failed (via command prompt as well as eclipse ).

```
package jenkov;

public class CheckProg {

public int math(int i) {
    try {
        int result = i / 0;
        // throw new IOException("in here");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return 10;
    } 
    finally {
        return 11;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CheckProg c1 = new CheckProg();
    int res = c1.math(10);
    System.out.println("Output :" + res);
}
}
enter code here
```

Error Observed : Could not find or load main class

Comment: this is correct.. output should be 11

Comment: You can find a very good explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18093929/3790546

Comment: Tried from Command Prompt a same program placed at a fresh location, ouptut reicieved 11. However when the same program is run from Eclipse IDE, output is Error: Could not find or load main class

Comment: You'll need to add some insights on your Eclipse setup then. Are you able to launch other programs from Eclipse, HelloWorld for example?

Comment: yes, other programs are running successfully from Eclipse